# Push to Heroku Rejected - How do I roll back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm currently learning Ruby on Rails using Michael Hartl programming book. I've recently managed to make my Sample APP crash. When commands do I use to revert my local machine back to an earlier version such as those which I've committed to Heroku.

It's currently running fine on Heroku, but wont display on the local machine.

Comment: The tutorial uses a separate git branch per chapter, which you only merge with the master branch after testing etc. So you should be able to switch back to the the master branch (then don't merge), then start again perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another option which is easier then tracking git commits and branch in your case, is just to delete your project folder locally and clone your working stuff from heroku back to your machine. Getting rid of any mess you may have on local repo.
Just make sure you get right next time.

```
heroku git:clone -a yourprojectappname
```

else you can do this below.

```
git log
```

(see your git commits log)

```
git log -n 1 xxxxxxx
```

(which 'x' is the first seven number of your commit you want to restore to get a more detailed info from that commit)

```
git reset --hard xxxxxxx
```

(which 'x' is the commit you want to restore)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean which Git command do you use to revert back to an old commit. 
You can do this `git reset --hard <commit number>`

The commit number can be found on the activity page of Heroku
you might also want to read [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes) about ways to undo changes using Git